# Wake timers in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wake-up

Is there a way for a wake timer to wake the computer up from sleep, do its business then make it sleep again? I found out that everytime a waketimer wakes up my windows 10 pc, it doesn't make it go to sleep again.

Comment: Going back to sleep should be the default behavior of your computer. As with any power management and wake time issues, you should check for an install any and all updated drivers and firmware for your computer, and make certain all software is fully patched.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already checked for and installed any and all updated drivers and firmware for your computer and have fully patched the computer and all software, then...

Run the command `powercfg /systemsleepdiagnostics` to see what is waking your computer, and more importantly, what is KEEPING it awake. This will likely point you in a direction for troubleshooting and hopefully, resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You could run Microsoft's psshutdown.exe with the -d command line parameter to put the pc to sleep.

In other words, when the pc wakes, have the wake task also launch a .bat or .cmd that runs the psshutdown command.  The psshutdown command can accept an additional command line parameter that specifies the number of seconds to wait before going to sleep, to allow enough time for the work to complete.

Alternatively, depending on the details of the work, you might be able to have the waking task run a controlling script that launches the work, waits for the work to somehow signal when it's completed, and then runs psshutdown, so that you won't need to guess the number of seconds that the work will take.